# Yii2 Связывание посредством промежуточной таблицы

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, yii, activerecord

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите пожалуйста во View нужно вывести все платформы которые есть у игры, со связыванием посредством промежуточной таблицы сталкиваюсь впервые написал так 
    `public function getPlatform(){
        return $this->hasMany(Platform::className(), ['platform_id' => 'fk_platform_id'])
            ->viaTable('game_platform', ['fk_game_id' => 'id']);
    }`
 все это в модели GamePlatform

Comment: В чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: проблема в том что $model->platform->name выдает NULL

Comment: В коде проблемы не вижу. мб данные в базе связаны неправильно?

Comment: `все это в модели GamePlatform` этот метод должен быть в Game

Comment: Да спасибо вам большое все зарабатало!

Comment: Просто из любопытства зачем вам в таблице game_platform искусственный первичный ключ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все это в модели GamePlatform этот метод должен быть в Game